# Random peaks in Mysql load slowing all users

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

We have a site that has been working pretty well for the past 2 years. But we are actually seeing random peaks in the database load that make the site very slow for a few seconds.

These peaks only appear from a certain load on the server and are impossible to predict. More users = more peaks. Everything run very smoothly outside of those peaks (page load is < 300ms). CPU and RAM are not impacted by those peaks.

Spikes are especially visible in db connections were it can go from 100 connections to 1000 connections for 2 or 3 seconds. Then back to normal.

We have nothing in the PHP log, nothing in the slow query log (long_query_time = 0.1).

Server : Debian / MariaDB 10.3.31, Apache 2.4.38, PHP 7.3.31 All tables are InnoDB with primary keys. Connection by socket. Codeigniter 4.1.7. Redis cache.

**What we already try :**

Reboot the server / Restart Mysql

Slow query log with long_query_time = 0 for 24h then pt-query-digest on the result. Everything is ok.

General log for 3h when heavy traffic then pt-query-digest on the result. Everything is ok.

Explain on each request of the logs. Everything looks fine.

We no longer know where to look to find the source of the problem.

**Additional info:**

Environment : VMware virtual machine | CPU : 16x Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6240R CPU @ 2.40GHz | RAM : 31.39 GiB | Disks : SSDs via SAN network

`SHOW VARIABLES` : https://pastebin.com/fx99mrdt

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUTS` : https://pastebin.com/NY1PKqpp

`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` : https://pastebin.com/bNcKKTYN

`MYSQL TUNNER` : https://pastebin.com/8gx9Qp1j

**EDIT 1:**

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE *******.eleves_tchat
     SET lu = 'true'
     WHERE id_etablissement = '266'
       AND id_eleve = '512385'
       AND auteur = 'enseignant'
       AND lu = 'false';

 id | select_type | table        | type        | possible_keys                                                      | key                                                             | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra
----|-------------|--------------|-------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|---------|------|------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | SIMPLE      | eleves_tchat | index_merge | fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_etablissement,lu,fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_eleve | fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_eleve,fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_etablissement | 4,4     | NULL | 1    | Using intersect(fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_eleve,fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_etablissement); Using where
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE eleves_tchat;

CREATE TABLE `eleves_tchat` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `id_etablissement` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_eleve` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `auteur` enum('eleve','enseignant') NOT NULL,
 `message` text NOT NULL,
 `lu` enum('false','true') NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_etablissement` (`id_etablissement`),
 KEY `lu` (`lu`),
 KEY `fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_eleve` (`id_eleve`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_eleve` FOREIGN KEY (`id_eleve`) REFERENCES `eleves` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_etablissement` FOREIGN KEY (`id_etablissement`) REFERENCES `mydomain_common`.`etablissements` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=610190 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mydomain_enseignant WHERE name = 'eleves_tchat'

+--------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
|     Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment |   Create_time    |   Update_time    | Check_time |     Collation     | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| eleves_tchat | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 64917 |            105 |     6832128 |               0 |      4374528 |   4194304 |         610189 | 17/01/2022 10:10 | 07/03/2022 10:29 | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL     |                |         |                0 | N         |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
```

**EDIT 3:**

With composite index and OPTIMIZE'd eleves_tchat table.

```
EXPLAIN UPDATE mydomain_enseignant.eleves_tchat SET lu = 'true' WHERE id_etablissement = '266' AND id_eleve = '512385' AND auteur = 'enseignant' AND lu = 'false';

+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table     | type  |                     possible_keys                     |                 key                 | key_len | ref  | rows |           Extra           |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | eleves_tchat | range | fk_te_eleves_tchat_id_eleve,id_etablissement_id_el... | id_etablissement_id_eleve_auteur_lu |      10 | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using buffer |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+---------+------+------+---------------------------+

SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM mydomain_enseignant WHERE name = 'eleves_tchat'

+--------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
|     Name     | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment |   Create_time    |   Update_time    | Check_time |     Collation     | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | Max_index_length | Temporary |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
| eleves_tchat | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 62117 |            126 |     7880704 |               0 |      3178496 |   4194304 |         611015 | 07/03/2022 18:09 | 07/03/2022 18:20 | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci | NULL     |                |         |                0 | N         |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+------------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+------------------+-----------+
```

**EDIT 4:**

We are not using transactions on our app. `ROLLBACKs` are caused by the `check_mysql_health` plugin for Nagios that monitors the database by sending regular requests like this:

```
35211159 Query  SET autocommit=0
35211159 Query  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'
35211159 Query  SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime'
35211159 Query  SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb'
35211159 Query  SHOW /*!50000 global */ STATUS LIKE 'Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free'
35211159 Query  ROLLBACK
35211159 Quit
```

**EDIT 5:**

Since the initial question, we update our config with :

```
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
```

Spikes are always here, so here is the `pt-query-digest` of a one day slow.log with `long_query_time = 0`. Some queries are taking 30s+, but only during our daily sql dump backup.

`pt_query_slow_log` : https://pastebin.com/hKvz37ca

**EDIT 6:**

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE PASSATIONS;

CREATE TABLE `passations` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_eleve` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_module` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `type_seance` enum('normale','inversee','tutore') NOT NULL,
 `id_item` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` date NOT NULL,
 `heure` time NOT NULL,
 `format_question` enum('qcm','ouvert') NOT NULL,
 `type_question` enum('preparatoire','principale') NOT NULL,
 `duree` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `score` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `correction` enum('0','1') NOT NULL,
 `premier` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `num_reponse` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `reponses` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `justification` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
 `age` float NOT NULL,
 `methode` enum('evaluation','entrainement') NOT NULL,
 `niveau` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
 `num_eval` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 `timestamp_entrainement` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `mots_bleus` enum('false','true') NOT NULL,
 `question_preparatoire` enum('false','true') NOT NULL,
 `lecture_audio` enum('false','true') NOT NULL,
 `id_binome` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `font_size` enum('14','16','18','20') NOT NULL,
 `line_height` enum('25','30','35') NOT NULL,
 `letter_spacing` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL,
 `word_spacing` enum('0','5','10','15') NOT NULL,
 `font_family` enum('1','2','3','4') NOT NULL,
 `lire_couleur` enum('normal','syllabes','phonemes','muettes') NOT NULL,
 `phonemes` text NOT NULL,
 `expe` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `fk_te_passations_id_item` (`id_item`),
 KEY `fk_te_passations_id_module` (`id_module`),
 KEY `fk_te_passations_id_eleve` (`id_eleve`),
 KEY `id_eleve_id_module_premier_methode_type_seance_type_question` (`id_eleve`,`id_module`,`premier`,`methode`,`type_seance`,`type_question`) USING BTREE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_te_passations_id_eleve` FOREIGN KEY (`id_eleve`) REFERENCES `eleves` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_te_passations_id_item` FOREIGN KEY (`id_item`) REFERENCES `my_domain_common`.`items` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `fk_te_passations_id_module` FOREIGN KEY (`id_module`) REFERENCES `my_domain_common`.`modules` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81067688 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

EXPLAIN SELECT MAX(`id`) AS `id` FROM my_domain_enseignant.passations WHERE `id_eleve` IN ('499613','499611','499612','499614', '499615','499616','499617','499618','499619','499620', '499621','499622','499623','499624','499625','499626', '499627','499628','499629','499630','499631','499632', '499633','499634' ) AND `id_module` = '1' AND `type_seance` = 'normale' AND `type_question` = 'principale' AND `methode` = 'entrainement' AND `premier` = 1
  
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type |   table    | type  |                                                   possible_keys                                                   |                             key                              | key_len | ref  | rows |          Extra           |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | passations | range | fk_te_passations_id_module,fk_te_passations_id_eleve,id_eleve_id_module_premier_methode_type_seance_type_question | id_eleve_id_module_premier_methode_type_seance_type_question |       9 | NULL |  910 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

**EDIT 7:**

I wanted to illustrate what's happenning when we have ~500 online users. On image 1, everything is ok, average page load is under 300ms. And then you will see a big spike in image 2, slowing down every users and making page load over 3 seconds.

[Everything is ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLGOP.jpg) -------> [Then BOOM!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb3FD.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with your harddisk access? When flushing the tables to disk? Or, much more profane, maybe the system memory is exhausted and swapping starts?

Comment: You're only looking at the performance of the machine from _inside_ the vm. Its possible that external factors in the wider world of vm's are impacting yours. Maybe a new VM has been brought online that is stealing/overcommitting resources.

Comment: can you please change the stars to your SCHEMA an run a EPLAIN like this: **EXPLAIN UPDATE `*******`.`eleves_tchat` SET `lu` = 'true'
WHERE `id_etablissement` = '266'
AND `id_eleve` = '512385'
AND `auteur` = 'enseignant'
AND `lu` = 'false';** and post us the results

Comment: @BerndBuffen Edited the question with the result.

Comment: @arkascha Hard disks, memory, processor, nothing seems abnormal in the logs. Max disks access time is 390ms.

Comment: Have you ever OPTIMIZE'd any tables in your 3 years?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE eleves_tchat; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS eleves_tchat; for analysis of 'not gap' message in your SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS report.

Comment: Are you aware com_rollback is averaging 1 event every 21 seconds for your 36 days of STATUS reporting?  Google search for 'mysql rollback prevention tutorial' and you will find several resources to explore the cause and possible prevention.  Rollbacks are expensive and can usually be avoided.

Comment: "Everything is ok" let me see the query digest of the slowlog, anyway.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've edited with new requested information. I've never OPTIMIZE'd any tables because i was thinking that it was not necessary with InnoDB tables. I feel like i was wrong... I'm not familiar with rollbacks. I will try to figure out what is causing this situation with CodeIgniter. Maybe concurrent requests on same data?

Comment: @matrox445  Please OPTIMIZE TABLE eleves_tchat;  and then time your query. Let us know, the results of this SINGLE ACTION that some of the 'technicans' say is a WASTE OF TIME.

Comment: @matrox445 After timing test comment posted, please again post current text results of SHOW TABLE STATUS eleves_tchat; for analysis in detail of what OPTIMIZE has done for this one table.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've already add a composite index on this table like proposed by Rick James in his answer. Is it ok to OPTIMIZE with this modification or do you want me to come back to initial indexes?

Comment: @matrox445  As the table exists at this time.  No need to back track, please.

Comment: @matrox445 Ricks suggestion should have helped a ton.  OPTIMIZE ing the table addresses different issue that DOES affect performance 24 hours a day.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've edited with updated results after OPTIMIZE ing the table. I wouldn't be able to see the real results until tomorrow because the spikes on our app only happen between 9AM and 4PM.

Comment: @matrox445 Thanks for posting info.  Will be out of town until my Friday.  Will check back in then to see how your spikes have acted this week.  What country / time zone are you in?  We are GMT -6 hrs, Birmingham, AL  USA

Comment: @WilsonHauck France, GMT +1. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @WilsonHauck I found in the `general_log` where the `ROLLBACKs` come from. I edited my question with more information (Edit 4). Still spikes today. The `slow_log` is empty with `long_query_time = 0.1` so I set it to 0 to be able to do a `pt-query` on something.

Comment: @matrox445 We really need to Skype TALK when you have time.  Thanks

Comment: @WilsonHauck Unfortunately, I am French and my English is quite limited, especially when it comes to speaking... But we could maybe chat somewhere else?

Comment: @RickJames I've updated my question with a pt-query-digest of the slow.log (edit 5).

Comment: I see `├á` in the a call to `DATE_FORMAT`; are you having charset issues?  Or maybe pt-query-digest is stumbling?

Comment: @RickJames I've check the full .log file, these requests are with "à", as expected. pt-query-digest probably have some trouble with characters encoding.

Comment: @matrox445 We can Skype Chat conveniently and share screen will be available, if needed. Have your spikes settled down?

Comment: @WilsonHauck So, I've updated a lot of things since my last post. I've fixed some queries, and I know use the Redis cache for a lot of stuff. This has considerably reduced the number of sql requests. Slow.log is completely empty with a long_query_time = 0.1. Sadly, nothing has changed, spikes are always here. I'm starting to think it has nothing to do with SQL queries. I've updated my post with a pt-query-digest of the general.log and an image of what i'm seeing (edit 7).

Comment: @matrox445 We can Skype Chat conveniently and share screen will be available, if needed.   In EDIT 1 there is NO NEED for quotes around INT values when matching your ID's, specifically  id_etablissemenr AND id_eleve.  Doing this dumbs down what would have been direct integer compare to string compare and takes more CPU time.  Thanks for the graphs.  Let's Skype Chat, please.  What country/time zone?  We are GMT -6 hrs, Birmingham AL USA

Comment: @WilsonHauck I'm using the Codeigniter query builder, and it looks like it's escaping each part of the queries. I'll focus on fixing this problem. I'm in France, GMT+1. Let me know when it's convenient for you!

Comment: @matrox445  My 7 AM would likely be about 2 PM for you and most days that will work.  Try on youw Wed 2 PM, please.  Search on Skype.com for  wlhauck@aol.com 
 Thanks, Wilson

Comment: @WilsonHauck Wednesday is not a really busy day for our plateform. Tomorow would be better to see live spikes. I'll try to contact you tomorow at 2PM (7AM for you). Thanks!

Comment: Tomorrow will be good, +2h20m, appx top of the hour. Thank you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sorry, my english is quite limited, and I'm not sure to understand your last message?

Comment: Please try to reach me tomorrow your 2 PM. Thanks

Comment: @matrox445     What will your Skype ID be?  Thanks, Wilson Hauck

Comment: My first question will be what is result of SELECT @@long_query_time;  and second question will be what are results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%dirty%';  Thanks, Wilson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have probably found the cause of our problem. This seems to be related to the locking mechanism of PHP sessions when using the Redis Handler in Codeigniter 4 with concurrent Ajax requests.

Since we moved from Redis to File sessions, the spikes no longer appears and everything run smoothly.

For more information, see this opened issue on Codeigniter 4 github : https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/issues/4391

Many thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: I'm using Symfony4 and experienced similar situation after updating packages via composer. 
MariaDB's Threads_connected spikes on peek time without any reason. 
Downgrading some packages to the past resolved this issue. 
Thank you my life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

"intersect" is less efficient than a composite index.

Have an index with these 4 columns in any order:

```
(id_etablissement, id_eleve, auteur, lu)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.  That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

---

```
Analysis of GLOBAL STATUS and VARIABLES:
```

**Observations:**

- Version: 10.3.31-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log
- 31.39 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 35d 21:04:32
- 87.2 QPS

**The More Important Issues:**

Well, not much is very important...

Since you have "SSDs via SAN network", some settings that may help:

```
innodb_io_capacity = 1000
innodb_flush_neighbors = 0
```

It seems that your dataset is significantly less than the RAM size, so the comments below on `innodb_buffer_pool_size` will be contradictory.  No change to that setting is needed now.

`Max_used_connections` is rather high.  If this occurs occassionally, then it might be wise to look into the spikes.  If it is frequent, then look into closing idle connections, etc.

Some settings to cut back on excessive use of RAM:

```
tmp_table_size      = 100M
max_heap_table_size = 100M
host_cache_size = 1000
thread_pool_max_threads = 2000
```

Other settings:

```
max_connect_errors = 1000
```

Why lots of `ROLLBACKs`, but essentially no `COMMITs`?  Do you use `autocommit`; if so, at what value?  (It was `ON` at the time of the `SHOW`, but that could have been coincidence.)

**Details and other observations:**

`( innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 6,144 / 33704755855.36 = 19.1%` -- % of RAM used for InnoDB buffer_pool
-- Set to about 70% of available RAM. (To low is less efficient; too high risks swapping.)

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth * innodb_page_cleaners ) = 1,024 * 4 = 4,096` -- Amount of work for page cleaners every second.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixable by lowering lru_scan_depth: Consider 1000 / innodb_page_cleaners (now 4). Also check for swapping.

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024` -- innodb_lru_scan_depth is a very poorly named variable. A better name would be innodb_free_page_target_per_buffer_pool. It is a number of pages InnoDB tries to keep free in each buffer pool instance to speed up read and page creation operations.
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- When flushing, use this many IOPs.
-- Reads could be slugghish or spiky. Use 2000 if using SSD drive.

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 193,281 / 393216 = 49.2%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size (now 6442450944) is bigger than necessary?

`( Uptime / 60 * innodb_log_file_size / Innodb_os_log_written ) = 3,099,872 / 60 * 512M / 44932925440 = 617` -- Minutes between InnoDB log rotations Beginning with 5.6.8, innodb_log_file_size can be changed dynamically; I don't know about MariaDB. Be sure to also change my.cnf
-- (The recommendation of 60 minutes between rotations is somewhat arbitrary.) Adjust innodb_log_file_size (now 536870912). (Cannot change in AWS.)

`( innodb_flush_method ) = innodb_flush_method = fsync` -- How InnoDB should ask the OS to write blocks. Suggest O_DIRECT or O_ALL_DIRECT (Percona) to avoid double buffering. (At least for Unix.) See chrischandler for caveat about O_ALL_DIRECT

`( default_tmp_storage_engine ) = default_tmp_storage_engine =`

`( Innodb_row_lock_waits/Innodb_rows_inserted ) = 123,721/2791251 = 4.4%` -- Frequency of having to wait for a row.

`( innodb_flush_neighbors ) = innodb_flush_neighbors = 1` -- A minor optimization when writing blocks to disk.
-- Use 0 for SSD drives; 1 for HDD.

`( innodb_io_capacity ) = 200` -- I/O ops per second capable on disk . 100 for slow drives; 200 for spinning drives; 1000-2000 for SSDs; multiply by RAID factor. Limits write IO requests per second (IOPS).
-- For starters: HDD: 200; SSD: 2000.

`( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON` -- Whether to use the adapative hash (AHI).
-- ON for mostly readonly; OFF for DDL-heavy

`( innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit ) = 2` -- 1 = secure; 2 = faster
-- (You decide) Use 1, along with sync_binlog (now 0)=1 for the greatest level of fault tolerance. 0 is best for speed. 2 is a compromise between 0 and 1.

`( sync_binlog ) = 0` -- Use 1 for added security, at some cost of I/O =1 may lead to lots of "query end"; =0 may lead to "binlog at impossible position" and lose transactions in a crash, but is faster. 0 is OK for Galera.

`( innodb_adaptive_hash_index ) = innodb_adaptive_hash_index = ON` -- Usually should be ON.
-- There are cases where OFF is better. See also innodb_adaptive_hash_index_parts (now 8) (after 5.7.9) and innodb_adaptive_hash_index_partitions (MariaDB and Percona). ON has been implicated in rare crashes (bug 73890). 10.5.0 decided to default OFF.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( max_connections ) = 2,000` -- Maximum number of connections (threads). Impacts various allocations.
-- If max_connections (now 2000) is too high and various memory settings are high, you could run out of RAM.

`( join_buffer_size * Max_used_connections ) = (4M * 1075) / 33704755855.36 = 13.4%` -- (A metric for pondering the size of join_buffer_size.)
-- join_buffer_size (now 4194304) should probably be shrunk to avoid running out of RAM.

`( min( tmp_table_size, max_heap_table_size ) ) = (min( 500M, 500M )) / 33704755855.36 = 1.6%` -- Percent of RAM to allocate when needing MEMORY table (per table), or temp table inside a SELECT (per temp table per some SELECTs). Too high may lead to swapping.
-- Decrease tmp_table_size (now 524288000) and max_heap_table_size (now 524288000) to, say, 1% of ram.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile (now ON) = ON is a potential security issue

`( Com_rollback / (Com_commit + Com_rollback) ) = 149,370 / (1 + 149370) = 100.0%` -- Rollback : Commit ratio
-- Rollbacks are costly; change app logic

`( (Com_insert + Com_update + Com_delete + Com_replace) / Com_commit ) = (2879857 + 51107135 + 14596 + 0) / 1 = 5.4e+7` -- Statements per Commit (assuming all InnoDB)
-- Low: Might help to group queries together in transactions; High: long transactions strain various things.

`( binlog_format ) = binlog_format = MIXED` -- STATEMENT/ROW/MIXED.
-- ROW is preferred by 5.7 (10.3)

`( Max_used_connections ) = 1,075` -- High-water mark for connections
-- Lots of inactive connections is OK; over 100 active connections is likely to be a problem. Max_used_connections (now 1075) does not distinguish them; Threads_running (now 7) is instantaneous.

`( Max_used_connections / host_cache_size ) = 1,075 / 703 = 152.9%`
-- Increase host_cache_size (now 703)

`( max_connect_errors ) = 100,000` -- A small protection against hackers.
-- Perhaps no more than 200.

`( Connections ) = 34,587,635 / 3099872 = 11 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout (now 28800); use pooling?

`( thread_pool_max_threads ) = 65,536` -- One of many settings for MariaDB's thread pooling
-- Lower the value.

**Abnormally small:**

```
Created_tmp_files = 0.036 /HR
Delete_scan = 0
Handler_read_first = 11 /HR
Table_locks_immediate = 8 /HR
eq_range_index_dive_limit = 0
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Access_denied_errors = 54,974
Com_show_events = 0.29 /HR
Com_show_master_status = 32 /HR
Com_show_profile = 0.0081 /HR
Com_show_status = 0.23 /sec
Feature_locale = 34 /HR
Handler_discover = 0.06 /HR
Tc_log_page_size = 4,096
Threads_connected = 616
log_slow_rate_limit = 100
max_heap_table_size = 500MB
min(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size) = 500MB
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
Innodb_have_snappy = ON
Slave_heartbeat_period = 0
Slave_received_heartbeats = 0
ft_boolean_syntax = "+ -><()~*:""""&"
lc_messages = fr_FR
log_slow_disabled_statements = admin,sp
log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
old_alter_table = DEFAULT
```

Comment: (added analysis of VARIABLES and STATUS)

Comment: Thank you for this complete report ! I'm not familiar with rollbacks. I will try to figure out what is causing this situation with CodeIgniter. And I will take a closer look at your recommendations.

Comment: Since we are not using transactions on our app, it's hard to find what caused these rollbacks. Do you know if it's possible to log the rollback transactions somewhere?

Comment: @matrox445 - The "general log" is a sledgehammer that would capture _explicit_ `ROLLBACKs` while capturing _everything_.  It is probably not worth trying.  This is one of several anomalies with `Com_rollback` that I have not been able to figure out.  "Com_x" _usually_ counts exactly how many times the code performed the SQL statement "x".  But, in your case, maybe it means something else.  Sorry.

Comment: The Com_rollback counter seems to increment regularly, every 30 seconds or so. It might be worth a try with the general log for a few minutes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found in the general_log where the rollbacks come from. I edited my question with more information (Edit 4).

Comment: @matrox445 - Well, Nagios is being sloppy.  Naughty Nagios.  Thanks for discovering that!

Comment: @matrox445 - I'm glad you figured out the composite index.  Does that speed things up enough to solve the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to have worked on the spikes. I will probably make a point at the end of the week.

Answer (score 0):

"Using intersect" is a clear indication of the need for a composite index.

Note that `OPTIMIZE` increased Data_length!  Yeah, that can happen; it's just another reason to avoid `OPTIMIZE`.

**Query 1**

This is executed 5 times per second; can some invocations be avoided.

```
SELECT  MAX(`id`) AS `id`
    FROM  my_domain_enseignant.passations
    WHERE  `id_eleve` IN ('499613','499611','499612','499614',
                '499615','499616','499617','499618','499619','499620',
                '499621','499622','499623','499624','499625','499626',
                '499627','499628','499629','499630','499631','499632',
                '499633','499634'
                         )
      AND  `id_module` = '1'
      AND  `type_seance` = 'normale'
      AND  `type_question` = 'principale'
      AND  `methode` = 'entrainement'
      AND  `premier` = 1\G
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE passations`.  I would like to see what indexes that table has.  Optimal would be a 8-column, composite and covering, index.  However, I tend to avoid that many columns.  Also, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT`.  If that says "Index merge" then it will definitely be better to have a composite index, even if not a full 6 columns.

**Query 2**

7 times per second.

```
SELECT  ge.`id_eleve` as `id`, ea.`last_activity`,
        COUNT(DISTINCT et.id) AS nb_messages,
        DATE_FORMAT(ea.connexion, "%d/%m/%Y ├á %H:%i") AS connexion,
        AES_DECRYPT(e.nom, 'key') as nom,
        AES_DECRYPT(e.prenom, 'key') as prenom
    FROM  `groupes_eleves` AS ge
    JOIN  `eleves` AS e  ON e.`id` = ge.`id_eleve`
    JOIN  `eleves_activity` AS ea  ON ea.`id_eleve` = ge.`id_eleve`
    LEFT JOIN  `eleves_tchat` AS et
               ON (et.`id_eleve` = ge.`id_eleve`
              AND  `auteur` = "eleve"
              AND  `lu` = "false")
    WHERE  ge.`id_groupe` IN ('44100','44194')
    GROUP BY  ge.`id_eleve`\G
```

With these composite and covering indexes:

```
groupes_eleves:   INDEX(id_groupe, id_eleve)
eleves_activity:  INDEX(id_eleve,  last_activity, connexion)
eleves_tchat:     INDEX(id_eleve,  id)  -- you have this (see Note)
```

When adding a composite index, DROP index(es) with the same leading columns.
That is, when you have both INDEX(a) and INDEX(a,b), toss the former.

Note: In InnoDB, a secondary key implicitly has a copy of the PK tacked on the end.  Hence, `INDEX(x)` and `INDEX(x,id)` are equivalent.

**Query 3**

```
UPDATE `my_domain_enseignant`.`eleves_activity`
    SET `last_activity` = 1646889907
    WHERE `id_eleve` = '456599'\G
```

Big Lock time -- Is the table InnoDB?  If it is MyISAM, that that is a big problem.

Is `id_eleve` the `PRIMARY KEY`?  If not, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE eleves_activity`

Usually <1ms, but up to 37s !  If InnoDB and proper key, then I have to say that *something else* is occasionally blocking things.

This is an example of where setting `long_query_time = 1` (or anything less than 37) would actually discover a problem due to this query that *should* take <1ms.

**Query 4**

Same symptoms and probably same cause as Query 3.

**Query 5**

```
SELECT  gc.`id`, gc.`description`, u.`prenom`, u.`nom`, g.`id` as `id_groupe`
    FROM  `groupes_calibrations` AS gc
    JOIN  `groupes` AS g  ON g.`id` = gc.`id_groupe`
    JOIN  `users` AS u  ON u.`id` = g.`id_enseignant`
    WHERE  gc.`id_groupe` IN ('48587')
      AND  gc.`statut` = 'ouvert'\G
```

Since "Rows_examined" very low, I suspect you have an adequate index now.  Otherwise, I would recommend:

```
gc:  INDEX(statut, id_groupe, description) -- if description not TEXT
gc:  INDEX(statut, id_groupe) -- if description is TEXT
```

**Postlog**

Fix some of the above, then run the slowlog again.  See what bubbles up to the top of the list.

Go back to the raw slowlog (if available) and find out what queries *ended* at the same time as that 37s Update ended.  There are probably lots of queries ending at that instant; one of them is the villain.  (Note: timestamps in the slowlog represent the *end* of the query.)

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback! As i said in my edit, some queries are taking 30s+ (4 requests in the entire slow.log from yesterday), but only during our daily sql dump backup. This backup happen every morning at 6AM, so it never happen when our app is really used.

Comment: I've edited the question with `SHOW CREATE` and `EXPLAIN` on passations table (edit 6). Query 5 has low rows_examinated because the table is almost empty.

Comment: @RickJames When you add an index, growth is reasonable..

Comment: @matrox445 - OK, the dump is the villian.  Are you using mysqldump?  Or something else.  Research the alternatives (replication, clustering, LVM, percona, etc)

Comment: @RickJames We are using mysqldump. But i'm not sure to understand, are you saying that our daily backup is causing the spikes? As i said, this backup happen only one time in the morning, causing some delays in sql requests during approximatively 30 seconds. I'll try to optimize some queries, and will be back shortly.

Comment: @RickJames So, I've updated a lot of things since my last post. I've fixed some queries, and I know use Redis cache for a lot of stuff. This has considerably reduced the number of sql requests. Slow.log is completely empty with a `long_query_time = 0.1`. Sadly, nothing has changed, spikes are always here. I'm starting to think it has nothing to do with SQL queries. I've updated my post with a pt-query-digest of the general.log and an image of what i'm seeing (edit 7).

Comment: Strange -- 52K queries in 100 seconds, yet only 8 QPS.

Comment: Does the general log cover the spike shown in the .img?  (I think not.)  It would be good to have either the slow or general log that spans the spike.

Comment: @RickJames I used this command: `perl pt-query-digest.pl --type genlog general.log > general_digest.txt`. Seems that it count `CONNECT` and `QUIT` as individual queries but i'm not sure. Spikes are happening regularly, so the general.log is covering a lot of them. Our daily slow.log remains empty despite the spikes.

Comment: @matrox445 - The digest of the general log that you provided covers only 100 minutes.

Comment: @RickJames Hmmm, ok, something went wrong. I've deleted the link and will post a new digest after a full busy day. Sorry for that!